# low rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

[image]

if 
$$
M_{2\times 2} = \pmatrix{1&5\\2&?}.
$$
If rank 1, $M_i = a_{ij} M_j$ and rank 2, $M_i=a_{ij} M_j+ a_{ik}M_k$, what is the explanation? I could not understand it. Please help. Thank you.  could help to provide the example.

Comment: What does $P_\Omega$ mean?  What are $X$ and $M$?

Comment: PΩ mean sampling operator for Ω is the index set of observed entries

Comment: $m_i$ are the columns of $M$?